# Docker execute multiple commands by passing CMD argument

Tags: shell-script, docker

After my docker start running, I need to execute some configuration.

Therefore, I put all my setting in the `./init.sh` and set the `ENTRYPOINT` like

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./init.sh"]
```

However,  I have to execute additional commands from users.
For example,

```
docker run -it name:tag pwd > a; pwd > b
```

The above command obviously won't work!

Then, I kind of getting stuck here.
If I pass my command like the above, I believe the `ENTRYPOINT` will become

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./init.sh", "pwd", ">", "a", ";", "pwd", ">", "b"]
```

Right? Does that mean I have to parse all the following parameter and execute in the `init.sh`?  Is there any better or correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final arguments in the `docker run` command are passed as arguments to the command defined in ENTRYPOINT. What you may want is an ENTRYPOINT that point to a script like this;

```
# Do theConfiguration 
...
# Run the user commands
sh -c "$*"
```

In the simple case you can use it with bare args:

```
docker run name:tag pwd
```

For more complex commands you would put everything in quote to avoid parsing by the host shell:

```
docker run name:tag "pwd > a; pwd > b"
```

But you have to consider where the redirected output goes. As coded above it ends up in two files inside the container, if you want to see it outside of the container you'll have to mount volumes.

Comment: This `sh -c "$*"` works like magic! Thanks